# Scala implement inline trait method

Tags: scala, playframework, traits

I've started learning scala and the play framework. I downloaded the sample project from the play framework site. I have a newbie question because I cannot understand the following syntax:

```
def count = Action { Ok(counter.nextCount().toString) }
```

What exactly does it do? `Action` is implemented function in BaseController, where action builder is assigned.
What is the content the beetwen braces for? Wat do the braces mean in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In playframework, requests are handled by `Actions`. When you invoke `Action { ... }`, you are actually invoking `play.api.mvc.Action` helper object to create `Action` values.

```
object Action extends ActionBuilder[Request] { ... }
```

If you look closely to `Action` object, it extends to `play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder` trait. This trait contains various `overloaded` `apply` methods that creates `Action` values. Therefore, when you are invoking `Action{ ... }` you are actually invoking `Action.apply({...})` and this `apply` method is inherited from `ActionBuilder` trait. If you look into `ActionBuilder` trait, you will see various higher ordered `apply` functions.

Now in your case, `def count = Action { Ok(counter.nextCount().toString) }`

You are actually invoking `apply` method with default content and no request parameter.

```
final def apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent] = apply(_ => block)
```

That means, you are providing block `{ Ok(counter.nextCount().toString) }` which return `Ok` Result.

**What is the content the beetwen braces for? Wat do the braces mean in this context?**

When you do `Action { Ok(counter.nextCount().toString) }`, you are actually invoking:

```
Action.apply(Ok(counter.nextCount().toString))
```

In scala, `apply` method is a factory method and therefore you  don't have to essentially call apply method, therefore you can also do `Action(Ok(counter.nextCount().toString))`. Additionally, if your function takes only single parameter, you can replace `()` brackets with curly braces `{}`. i.e. you can do `Action{Ok(counter.nextCount().toString)}`.

I would suggest to look into function literals, higher ordered functions, by-name parameter, method currying etc. So, that you will have more insight in these.

Comment: Just to add to this, the content within the `Action` braces is what you are returning. `Ok` is the HTTP response code you return to whoever sent a request to your controller - ie a `200` response (other common ones are `BadRequest` [400], `NotFound` [404], `NoContent` [204], etc). Within the `Ok` is the body of the response; in this case, you are just returning a String of some sort, but you can also return whole webpages (called `views` in Play), results of other function calls (eg if you are making a backend API), or nothing at all.

Answer (score 0):

The source code will give you the details:

```
/**
   * Constructs an `Action` with default content, and no request parameter.
   *
   * For example:
   * {{{
   * val hello = Action {
   *   Ok("Hello!")
   * }
   * }}}
   *
   * @param block the action code
   * @return an action
   */
  final def apply(block: => Result): Action[AnyContent] =
    apply(BodyParsers.utils.ignore(AnyContentAsEmpty: AnyContent))(_ => block)
```

It's equivalent to `def count =  Action.apply(Ok(counter.nextCount().toString))`